Taylor expansion for a differential operator
I'm struggling with a problem in which I need to expand a differential operator near a known function. The problem is the following:
$L(u)$ is a differential operator, in my problem: $L(u)$ is defined as
$$L(u)=u^{\prime\prime}+(u^\prime)^2+g(t)u^\prime+k(t)$$
I know a solution $v$, where $u-v=\delta u$ is small. So I want to expand the operator applied to the unknown function $u$ as something like
$$L(u)\sim L(v)+L^\prime(v)\,\delta u+o(\delta u^2)$$
Where I understand that $L^\prime(v)$ is related to the Gateoux derivative, but I'm not sure of this and also don't know how to calculate.
If someone know something about this and want to share I'll be very grateful.

Your reasonind is correct. You compute $L(u+\delta u)$ and keep only the terms linear in $\delta u$. Here, we have
$$
L(v+\delta u) = (v+\delta u)'' + (v'+\delta u')^2 + g(t)(v+\delta u) + k(t).
$$
If we expand out the quadratic, we will find
$$
L(v+\delta u) = L(v) + \delta u'' + 2v'\delta u' + g(t)\delta u + (\delta u')^2.
$$
The functional derivative is then given by
$$
L'(v)\delta u = \delta u'' + 2v'\delta u' + g(t)\delta u.
$$

Thanks! But I don't understand why appears $u'$ in the expression. And why the terms which include $\delta u'$ and $\delta u''$ disappear? The aim of the expansion is write my operator applied to a unknown function as things which I know, and I don't know $u'$, for example.

I edited my post to clarify that $L'(u)v$ is a linear operator evaluated at the point $u$ and applied to the function $\delta u$. $u'$ is present because of the cross terms that appear when you expand the binomial. In general, the derivative of any nonlinear functional will contain expressions involving the evaluation point, $u$ in this case. It's the same as how the derivative of $x^2$ contains $x$

Ok, but my idea is, from the expansion, write that
$\delta u=\frac{L(u)-L(v)}{L'(v)}$
where I know the value of $L(u)-L(v)$ and using this, if I can compute the value of $L'(v)$ I can estimate the value of $\delta u$. So I need compute the derivative and evaluate this in my known function $v(t)$.

I misread your question and thought that $u$ was the known function instead of $v$. I have rewritten my answer so that $v$ is the known function. I am not sure what the goal of your comment is, but this is what the derivative operator is.
